# Custom style for tikzcd

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I would like to define something called `fieldtower` (a style?) which stands for `arrows=no head, column sep=small`. This thing should be usable at will between `tikzcd` environments. So something like this

```
\begin{tikzcd}[style=fieldtower]
    ...
\end{tikzcd}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=no head, column sep=small]
    ...
\end{tikzcd}
```

Is there way to do this, that's better than a macro? I've tried the following tikz code, but using it in this context just produces a strange error.

```
\tikzstyle{fieldtower} = [arrows=no head, column sep=small]
```

Comment: Did you try `\newcommand{\fieldtower}{arrows=no head, column sep=small}` and `\begin{tikzcd}[\fieldtower]`?

Comment: @SebGlav Did *you* try?

Comment: I have to admit I didn't at this time (no computer to try) and that it was a dumb idea ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say

```
\tikzcdset{fieldtower/.style={arrows=no head, column sep=small}}
```

Note that `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for some years.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{fieldtower/.style={arrows=no head, column sep=small}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d] \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}[fieldtower]
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d] \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]